# Shape of weights in the Softmax layer in Word2vec(skip-gram)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, word2vec, softmax

I have a question about a shape of the weights for the Softmax Layer.

Suppose our vocabulary is 10000 words and our Embedding layer will reduce the dimensionality to 300.

So an Input is a one-hot-vector of length 10000 and Embedding layer has 300 neurons. It means, that weight matrix from Input layer to the Embedding layer has shape 10000*300(number of words in vocabulary* neurons in Embedding layer).

According to this tutorial(https://www.kaggle.com/christofer/word2vec-skipgram-model-with-tensorflow) and many others the next weight matrix(that connects Embedding layer and Softmax classifier) has the same shape(number of words in vocabulary* neurons in Embedding layer or in our case 10000 * 300). I don't understand why? Shouldnt it be 300 * 10000(because we have to predict 10000 probabilities for each class)?

Can you explain me this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the [`tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss) function. The way this function is designed, it needs the weight matrix to have the shape, `[vocabulary size, dim]`.

From the documentation,

> weights: A Tensor of shape [num_classes, dim], or a list of Tensor objects whose concatenation along dimension 0 has shape [num_classes, dim]. The (possibly-sharded) class embeddings.

### Why this is the case?

The way `sampled_softmax_loss` works is by sampling weights belonging to a subset of output nodes that are going to be optimized every iteration (i.e. not running optimization on weights for all output nodes). The way it's done is using [`embedding_lookup`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1733). Therefore, having the weight in the shape `[vocab_size, dim]` makes it ideal for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped! But is there some theoretical explanation why is that?

Comment: One possible reason is that it's much more straight-forward to sample weights related to each node (i.e grabbing a row in this orientation) in the softmax layer. For example if you use tf.gather it's basically passing 1D sequence of indices.

Comment: Edited my answer to say why this is the case.